# CSS Border crashed when height auto

Tags: html, css, border

I have HTML code like that

```
    <div class="ads-w1">
           <div class="ads-w2">
                   <div class="ads_cost"><span>$0.01</span></div>
                   <div class="ads_info">
                           <div class="title">Ads Title</div>
                   </div>
                   <div class="ads_banner">Ads Banner</div>
           </div>
    </div>
```

And the css codes like that

```
.ads-w1 {
    background: url("../img/ads-bg1.png") 0px 0px repeat-x #3ec2c5;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 0px 0px 12px;
}

.ads-w2 {
    background: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    height: 150px;
}

.ads_cost {
    float: left;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #525252;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
    width: 120px;
    background-color: #00BF00;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 54px;
}


.ads_info {
    float: left;
    width: 340px;
    overflow: hidden;
}


.ads_banner {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 490px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 8px;
}

.ads_info .title {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #278dff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and the output will be like that

[image]

I need to let .ads_w2 height to be "auto", something to be like that

```
 .ads-w2 {
    background: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    height: auto;
}
```

But is the problem is when i set it "auto" the border crashed

[image]

How i can solve that please ?

Thank you.

Comment: please post a jsFiddle so we can have a working example of what you're talking about ...

Comment: "I have PHP code like that [ some html ]" . No you don't!

Comment: you're floating divs inside ads-w2 ... making ads-w2 ignore height from divs inside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are floating the elements in `.ads-w2` and that causes your element to have a `0` height.

One possible solution is to add `overflow: hidden;` to `.ads-w2`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 .ads-w2 {
    background: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    height: auto;
    display:table; /* <----- this */
}
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/2fWj2/

Answer (score 0):

You do that correctly.But because you don't have any text or other thing in that `DIV` you see it with crash. even though `DIV` is a container only.
I fill this  `DIV` with  `P` some  tags.
[see this:](http://jsfiddle.net/talebihamid/CG8Lk/)